# How to remove brackets and commas from a list of tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I can't figure out how to get the correct output for my Cartesian Product code which should return a line of tuples:

(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)

but after removing the brackets from my list of tuples, my output looks like this:

(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)

How would I remove the extra commas to match the correct output?

My code:

```
import sys
n = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    n.append(line.rstrip().replace(" ", ""))
listA = n[0]
listB = n[1]
AxB = []
for a in listA:
    a = int(a)
    for b in listB:
        b = int(b)
        AxB.append((a,b))
result = str(AxB)[1:-1]
print(result)
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you have a list of tuples, you can print them like so: `print(*list_of_tuples, sep=" ")` If you want a string, you could do `" ".join(map(str, list_of_tuples))`.

Comment: You cannot remove the commas from *the list*, for the same reason that you cannot remove the brackets from the list: they are *not actually part of* the list. They are part of the *text used to display* that list. Just like how if you had the number `123`, you can't "remove the 2" from that. (For that matter, the number isn't "in" base 10, and doesn't "have" a base at all. Only the *way that you write it* has those things.) You could modify the text that you get from using `str` on the list, but it will be much easier to just *display the individual values*.